# Rails Initializer: An infinite loop in a separate thread to update records in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I want to run an infinite loop on a separate thread that starts as soon as the app initializes (in an initializer). Here's what it might look like:

```
# in config/initializers/item_loop.rb

Thread.new
  loop do
    Item.find_each do |item|
      # Get price from third-party api and update record.
      item.update_price!
      # Need to wait a little between requests to avoid getting throttled.
      sleep 5
    end
  end
end
```

I tend to accomplish this by running batch updates in recurring background jobs. But this doesn't make sense since I don't really need parallelization, downtime, or queueing, I just want to update one item at a time in a single thread, forever.

Yet there are multiple things that concern me:

1. **[Leaked Connections](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/07/17/activerecord-concurrency-in-rails4-avoid-leaked-connections/)**: Should I open up a new `connection_pool` for the thread? Should I use a gem like [safely](https://github.com/ankane/safely) to avoid crashing the thread?
2. **[Thread Safety](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/a-modern-guide-to-threads)**: Should I be worried about race conditions? Should I make use of `Mutex` and `synchronize`? Does using `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` impact thread safety?
3. **[Deadlock](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2016/12/29/concurrency-in-rails-5-0/)**: Should I use `Rails.application.executor.wrap`?
4. **[Concurrent Ruby/Sleep Intervals](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/TimerTask.html)**: Should I use `TimerTask` from `concurrent-ruby` gem instead of `sleep` or something other than `Thread.new`?

Information on any of these subjects is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to run this task in the background all the time? What does `update_price!` actually do? Why not just update changes items? Or items someone actually wants to see? `pause 5` means you cannot update more than 720 prices per hour, what if there are thousands of prices? It feels to me like this is not well designed...

Comment: 1. I need to run this task in the background continuously.

2. `update_price! # Gets price from third-party website and updates record.`

3. `sleep 5` means I cannot update more than 720 prices per hour, which is just what I need.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ there are _not_ 720 prices per hour, there are 720 _items_ per hour at most. To me it looks like the XY problem. It’s definitely a design flaw. I would run a separate worker using `cron`, updating _all the items_ once a, say, 1 minute.

Comment: @spickermann May I ask how you would design it, considering that it needs to run continuously? I'm open to ideas.

Comment: @spickermann The reason I need to wait a couple of seconds is because the third-party api throttles my requests. I need to wait a little while between them.

Comment: @mudasobwa I could run a separate worker with cron jobs, I've taken this approach before. It feels unnatural for this particular type of job since it runs for so long. I've solved this issue by batching jobs (loop: start job, grab a couple of items, begin next job, stop job). But I felt there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Usually to perform a job in a background process(non web-server process) a background workers manager is used. Rails has a specific interface for that manager called [ActiveJob](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) There are few implementation of a background workers manager - Sidekiq, DelayedJob, Resque, etc. [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) is preferred. Returning back to actual problem - you may create a schedule to run `UpdatePriceJob` every interval using gem [sidekiq-scheduler](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler) Another nice extension for throttling Sidekiq workers is [sidekiq-throttler](https://github.com/gevans/sidekiq-throttler)

Some code snippets:

```
# app/workers/update_price_worker.rb
# Actual Worker class
class UpdatePriceWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options throttle: { threshold: 720, period: 1.hour }

  def perform(item_id)
    Item.find(item_id).update_price!
  end
end

# app/workers/update_price_master_worker.rb
# Master worker that loops over items
class UpdatePriceMasterWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    Item.find_each { |item| UpdatePriceWorker.perform_async item.id }
  end
end

# config/sidekiq.yml
:schedule:
  update_price:
   cron: '0 */4 * * *'   # Runs once per 4 hours - depends on how many Items are there
   class: UpdatePriceMasterWorker
```

Idea of this setup - we run MasterWorker every 4 hours(this depends on how much time it takes to update all items). Master worker creates jobs to update price of an every particular item. `UpdatePriceWorker` is throttled to max 720 RPH.

Comment: Thank you! :) This is helpful and definitely one way to accomplish it.

For my particular use case, I'm looking for something more synchronous. I need to wait exactly 5 seconds between each call to `update_price!`. No need for async once I'm inside the master background job.

I would also like to keep the job running with as little downtime as possible. Might there be a way to restart the job once it's done?

I've been looking at alternatives and stumbled upon the idea of creating a [daemon](http://michalorman.com/2015/03/daemons-in-rails-environment). I think it solves my problem.

Comment: Yeah, restarting job once it is done could help here, but it requieres to be implemented in 100% of failure-proof because if a job fails it stops updating queue.

Answer (score 0):

I use [rails runner](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#bin-rails-runner) x ([god gem](http://godrb.com/) or [k8s](https://kubernetes.io/)) in our similar case.

Rails runner runs in another process so that we do not have to worry about connection-leak and thread-safety.

God-gem or k8s supports concurrency and monitoring the job failure.  Running 1 process with some specific sleep-time would promise third-party API throttles (running N process with N API-key could support speed up).

I think deadlock would happen in any concurrency situation.

I do not think this loop + sleep approach is a design flaw, because:

- cron always starts based on schedule so that long running jobs could run simultaneously.  We need to add a logic to avoid job overlapping.  Rather, just loop + sleep keeps maximum throughput without any job overlap.
- ActiveJob is good for one-shot long-running task, but it does not fit for daemon.